# Place input fields in a row to fit full container width

Tags: html, css

I try to put three input fields in a row, with a little bit of space next to each other, so it doesnt look odd.
Anyway the third input always gets a new line, why is that and how to fix it?

What I want to achieve, see picture.

[image]

Html:

```
<div id="form">
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
</form>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#form{
width: 600px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#form input {
width: 33.33%;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 1.1% 0 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the width percentage of your inputs.  Those percentages add with the margin.

```css
#form {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#form input {
  width: 31.63%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1.1% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#form input:last-child {
  margin-right: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </form>
</div>
```

Or, if you can support flex layout, this is the cleanest.  **Margin is not needed** because `justify-content: space-between` handles spacing as long as the input percentages allow for it (add to < 100%).

```css
#form > form {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#form input {
  width: 31%;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: If you add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the inputs, you can go up to 33.3% width even.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `display: flex` to form:

```css
#form {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#form input {
  width: 33.33%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1.1% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
form {
  display: flex;/*Add display flex*/
}
form input:last-child {
  margin-right: 0 !important;/*remove margin-right from last input*/
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </form>
</div>
```

Also you can remove `margin-right` from last input.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/locakediji/1/edit?html,css,output

### CSS:

```css
#form{
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align:justify; // added
}

form::after{ content:''; width:100%; display:inline-block; } // added

#form input {
  width: 28%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rudie - dear Mr. Rudie, would you care to share on what browser does this happen and OS? simply saying "doesn't work" isn't professional

Comment: I didn't know professionalism was a SO requirement. Chrome stable on Win7. Min font-size 18px. The inputs don't have any styles applied to them....

Comment: @Rudie - I'm also on windows 7 with latest Chrome, everything works fine. I've been using this method for years. there must be some anomaly with your system, because this passed QA by many on production servers.